# variable no definida en mi cupon

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

estoy intentando hacer un cupon el cual consulte a traves de ajax si el cupon existe me mande una alerta que si existe y si no que me mande un error con un mensaje y hasta aca el codigo funciona pero al pasarle una variable pero me sale el siguiente error de variable precios_id no definida no se porque me sale

vista

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#cupon').on('blur', function(){
        $('#result-cupon').html('<img src="images/loader.gif" />').fadeOut(1000);

        var cupon = $(this).val();    
        var dataString = 'cupon='+cupon;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{asset('check_cupon_availablity.php')}}",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result-cupon').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
            }
        });
    });              
});    
</script>
</head>
<div class="">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="content" class="col-lg-8">
            <form action="#" method="post" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cupon">Cupon</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cupon" name="cupon" placeholder="Captura aquí tu cupón">
                    <label for="precios_id">precios_id</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="precios_id" name="precios_id" placeholder="" value="{{$xd}}">

                    <div style="background: #1abac7;width: 18%;border-radius: 10%" >
                    <img src="{{asset('images/lupa.png')}}" width="20px" style="margin-right: 11%" > Buscar
                    </div>
                    <div id="result-cupon" ></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>     
</div>
```

esta es la conexion a php que hace la consulta para saber si el cupon existe y quiero jalarme ademas de si existe su id check_cupon_availablity.php

```
<?php 

define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'prueba');

$connexion = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);



sleep(1);
if (isset($_POST)) {

    $cupon = (string)$_POST['cupon'];
    $precios_id = (string)$_POST['precios_id'];
  
    
    
    $result = $connexion->query(
        'SELECT * FROM precios WHERE cupon = "'.strtolower($cupon).'"'
    );
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Enhorabuena!</strong> Cupon valido. '.$cupon.' '.$precios_id.'<a class="btn" href="https://pagina.com/">dd</a>
    </div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Oh no!</strong> Cupon invalido.</div>';
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En Ajax los datos que estás mandando están en la variable `dataString`, pero en esa variable no estás mandando un valor para  `precios_id`, debes recuperar ese valor y mandarlo. Si quieres prueba esto, manual, y verás que funciona: **`var dataString = {cupon: cupon, precios_id: 18};`** construí el parámetro en forma de objeto porque es más claro y menos sujeto a errores que estar concatenando y puse un valor `18` a mano, en tu código sólo lo cambias por la variable que recogerá el `value` del input `precios_id`. Si no hay otros errores debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que estas enviando los datos por AJAX deberias incluir todos los datos necesarios: `cupon`, `precios_id`

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('#cupon').on('blur', function(){
    $('#result-cupon').html('<img src="images/loader.gif" />').fadeOut(1000);

    var cupon = $(this).val(); 
    var precios_id = $("#precios_id").val();   
    var dataString = 'cupon='+cupon+'&precios_id='+precios_id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{asset('check_cupon_availablity.php')}}",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#result-cupon').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
        }
    });
  });
```

});

Otra manera mas conveniente suponiendo que deseas enviar todos los valores del formulario, es usar la funcion `$(form).serialize()` para generar automaticamente los datos de POST

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{asset('check_cupon_availablity.php')}}",
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#result-cupon').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
        }
    });
```

Mejor aun puedes agregar un id al formulario

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="post" >
```

Y luego usarlo como referencia en `data:`

```
data: $("#myform").serialize(),
```

**EDIT:**

Para usar los valores en la respuesta utiliza:

```
if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $precio=$row["preciomx"];
  echo "<div class='....  $precio >"
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio mucho, una pregunta mas si quisiera imprimir un campo de la consulta de arriba en el echo div como lo podria hacer por ejemplo el campo preciomx de la tabla precios

Comment: Agregue un comentario acerca de eso. Saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias si me funciono nadamas la variable la puse entre  '.$precio.'